# Joseph Kaplan as quoted by Swami Prabhavananda?

Tags: philosophy

[Swami Prabhavananda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swami_Prabhavananda)'s *The Spiritual Heritage of India* (1962) quotes "the physicist Joseph Kaplan" several times (in the chapter on the Samkhya system). For instance:

> Thus the molecule is not something which takes on successive states,
>   but it is the states themselves. So dice are the sum of possible was
>   in which they can fall. The principle is known as the principle of
>   superposition. So the three gunas represent the universe, and as the
>   three occur in various relative intensities, so the properties of
>   things are determined.
>
> The atomic theory is the product of the Western mind. In his native
>   way the Western scientist generalizes the experience that one can
>   subdivide matter until one meets an ultimate particle into an atomic
>   theory assuming many elements. The Hindu philosopher goes much further
>   and reduces everything to one element.

Who is/was this Joseph Kaplan (for his is a fairly common name) and did he publish any books (perhaps also on spiritual topics) by himself?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Kaplan

Comment: Is there evidence that this is the *right*, not just *some* contemporary Joseph Kaplan?

Comment: Looking at his birth and death dates it fits with the same time period that Prabhavananda was alive and active.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I am not (yet) convinced.